# Html5 form validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have written simple from code with html5 validation.but its not working.its still go to the controller..This is my code.

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/RigesterValue');?>
<h4> Rigesteration </h4>
<table border="2" align="center">
<tr><td><label>First name</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" id="First_name" name="First_name" required pattern="[A-Z ]+"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Last name</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="Last_name"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>User name</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="User_name"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" maxlength="20" name="Password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Confirm Password</td>
<td><input type="password" maxlength="20" name="Confirm_Password"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Address</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="Address"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Cell number</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="Cell_number"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" maxlength="20" name="Email"></td></tr>
<tr><td><Label>Status</Label></td>
</td></tr><br>
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="Submit" value="Register"></td></tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?
```

I have apply html5 validation on just first field ..Which is First_name..but still it go to the controller page.

Comment: CodeIgniter will always post to a controller since you have an action.

Comment: so  what should i do ..if i want to validate in view

Comment: You would need a frontend validation. HTML 5 validation is good except I would not rely on that because not all browsers support it. [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) is a good frontend validation.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter's [own validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) often does the trick. It's most safe since it will receive values, validate them and *then* process them.

Validation through the browser isn't reliable due to things like Firebug and so on. In the end I can easily post whatever values I want to your page, and if validation only covers HTML5 etc, your system won't know what hit it.

Always let your server validate everything, but you may aswell let some thing be done **also** inside your view. For instance, finding an unoccupied username can be a hazzle if you need to post every time just to hear that it's taken, therefor the part can be done through ajax that checks if username is taken or not and shows before submit.

If you get form_validation to work as intended, you probably won't see much need for more ways to validate your fields.